# Not all code paths return a value error

Tags: c#, methods, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with my method. Environment prompts me that "not all code paths return a value". I don't understand why. I don't see this path which doesn't return a value. Can someone explain me why ? Thanks and regards.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community

```
private CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind CheckCode(String strCodeToCheck)
{
    String[] splitCode = strCodeToCheck.Split(new char[] { ',' });
    String strCode = splitCode[1];

    if (strCode == String.Empty)
    {
        // code incorrect
        return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_INCORRECT;
    }
    else
    {
        CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind resultToReturn;

        SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.CnnString);
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckCode", sqlCnn);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", strCode); 
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@IsUnique",
            DbType = DbType.Int32,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        });


        try
        {
            sqlCnn.Open();

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlCnn.Close();

            // 1 means is unique
            if ((Int32)sqlCmd.Parameters["@IsUnique"].Value == 1)
            {
                return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_OK;    
            }
            else // 0 means is NOT unique
            {
                return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_NOK;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            // error SQL while checking code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // general exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is returned when an exception is thrown?

Comment: Sorry ... It helped. Thanks

Comment: Well what is returned if you catch an `SQLException` after doing that?

Comment: Surely you must see where I am going with this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code paths must return a value including your catch blocks and as well as after the if/else statement:

```
private CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind CheckCode(String strCodeToCheck)
            {
                String[] splitCode = strCodeToCheck.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                String strCode = splitCode[1];

                if (strCode == String.Empty)
                {
                    // code incorrect
                    return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_INCORRECT;
                }
                else
                {
                    CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind resultToReturn;

                    SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.CnnString);
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckCode", sqlCnn);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", strCode); 
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@IsUnique",
                        DbType = DbType.Int32,
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                    });


                    try
                    {
                        sqlCnn.Open();

                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        sqlCnn.Close();

                        // 1 means is unique
                        if ((Int32)sqlCmd.Parameters["@IsUnique"].Value == 1)
                        {
                            return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_OK;    
                        }
                        else // 0 means is NOT unique
                        {
                            return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_NOK;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
                    {
                        // error SQL while checking code
                         return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_NOK;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // general exception
                        return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_NOK;
                    }
                }
                return CognexDataMan.EnumCodeKind.CODE_NOK;
            }
```

Comment: Yes it helped. Somehow I thought I've already checked that. Thanks